# What are the different events that can happen on a Salmon Run Map?

Tags: splatoon-2

Started Salmon Run today, and in some rounds, the map change or there is an event of some kind.

There seem to be a lower tide version (where you fight on the beach of the map), a higher tide version (where you can only play on upper parts of the maps), some fireflies thing, where enemies were quick and super aggressive, and I heard sometimes there's fog.

What possible "events" can happen on a map and what do they do?

Comment: I don't know if it's available online, but there's an ingame manual you can access in the salmon run lobby that contains this information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to one [Reddit guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/6p6bt7/guide_splatoon_2_salmon_run/), there are 9 different events.  I've summarized and listed them below, but the guide goes into much further detail:

- **Low Tide** - the water level decreases and egg collection moves
- **High Tide** - the water level increases
- **Fog** - visibility is limited.  The guide notes that other events can occur during fog
- **Night** - Similar to Fog, and appears to happen more often with the Griller or Mothership event
- **Grillers** - Grillers spawn in conjunction with Night
- **Cohock Charge** - Lots of Cohocks spawn and some cannons will also be available
- **The Mothership** - Spawns a helicopter that drops crates that spawn enemies.  One of the harder events according to the guide, and probably won't even happen unless you have around 180%-190% paygrade
- **Firefly/Rush** - Lots of Salmonids spawn and move faster than normal towards players with fireflies on them.
- **Goldie Seeking** - Lots of inkjet gushers appear spawning Salmonids and one Goldie.  You can tell which gusher will spawn the Goldie by how much golden light is coming off of it.